# Modbus implementation Linux C Embedded

Tags: c, linux, raspberry-pi, embedded-linux, modbus

Edited post. I excluded sqlite from causing an error.
I'm learing C in Linux embedded (Raspbian). I code modbus connection in while loop. It works a while - hour or more random time. And then it has a connection error and doesn't work. I stop a program and run again and works proper.
The error printed on command line is "Success", but it entering to if(modbus_connect(*ctx) == -1) which is an error:
My code below:

Definitions.h

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <bcm2835.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <modbus.h>
//Global variables
extern modbus_t *ctx;
```

Main.c

```
//Global variables
modbus_t *ctx;
(...)
 
int main() {
    (..variables declaration..)
while(1){
    (...)
    Curr_time_us = bcm2835_st_read();   // Read current time
    Curr_time = Curr_time_us / 1000;
    if(Curr_time > tTimer2 + timevalue + 100){
            ret = ModbusExecute(&ctx, &sht20);
            if( ret == 1){
                ctx = modbus_new_rtu("/dev/ttyUSB0", 9600, 'N', 8, 1);
                timevalue = 60000;
            }
            tTimer2 = bcm2835_st_read() / 1000;
        }
}
```

ModbusRtu.c

```
uint16_t ModbusExecute(modbus_t** ctx, struct climate_sensor *Czujnik){
uint16_t ModbusSts1, ModbusSts2;
if (*ctx == NULL){
    Czujnik->data_ok = FALSE;
    printf("Blad\n");
    return 1;
}
modbus_set_slave(*ctx, 8);
if (modbus_connect(*ctx) == -1){
    Czujnik->data_ok = FALSE;
    printf("Connection error %s\n", modbus_strerror(errno));
    return 1;
}
else{
    ModbusSts1 = modbus_read_input_registers(*ctx, 1, 1, &Czujnik->temperatura);
    //printf("Sts Temp %d    %d  ",ModbusSts1, Czujnik->temperatura);
    ModbusSts2 = modbus_read_input_registers(*ctx, 2, 1, &Czujnik->wilgotnosc);
    Czujnik->wilgotnosc += 12;
    //printf("Sts Wilg %d    %d\n",ModbusSts2, Czujnik->wilgotnosc);
    if(ModbusSts1 == 1 && ModbusSts2 == 1){
        Czujnik->data_ok = TRUE;
        printf("data OK %d address\n", ctx);
    }
    else Czujnik->data_ok = FALSE;
    return 2;
}
}
```

Can anyone give me some tips ?
Thanks

Comment: You provide a vague description, and post only some code fragments.  How do these programs execute for 48 hours when there are no loops? You neglect to mention how these two processes relate to each other.  Given the symptom of delayed failure, I'd guess that there's somekind of synchronization issue between processes that eventually fails or some sort of race condition?

Comment: Of course this modbus_execute funtion is in while(1) loop. Calling in fork - child (cpid == 0) and triggered by timer (current time > last reading time).
I printed out address of &ctx and when program starting the address is in decimal (%d) 1100516 and i'm printing address when error occurs and it prints 2127492500. How is it possible the address of global variable changed ?

Comment: The problem is that ModBus is the timebased protocol. To make it work _reliably_  you **must** use RTOS. Linux is not RTOS. (@sawdust JFYI)